# MS Access Print current data from form

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access, how to print current record from the current form and then refresh the record after the printing?

I can print, but it will print the whole data from the source.

Comment: Print a report, not form. Or apply filter to form before printing. Printing forms is seldom satisfactory. Why do you need refresh?

Comment: To be more specific i want to print report from current Form records and when data printed i need to insert new data. I tried both Me.Refresh and Me.Requery but with no hope

Comment: Data entered must first be committed to table. Then apply filter criteria when opening report. Then go to New Record row to enter new data.

Comment: In yet other words: reports are for printing so build a report that takes a single record and displays it (auto print after it is working).  Then add a button to the form that opens the report and passes the selected record as the parameter.  There are a bunch of ways to pass that parameter.  The first you tube video passes the parameter in the worst way, the second does a better job if far from the best:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kb2438eDRW4  , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3AQVZCEHmI